# Eager load related properties of specific type?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, eager-loading

Here is what my model looks like:

```
class Transaction {}

class Income : Transaction
{
  public IncomeType IncomeType {get;set;}
}

class Expense : Transaction
{
  public ExpenseType ExpenseType {get;set;}
}
```

I want to eager load transactions to include the `ExpenseType`s in the `Expense`s and `IncomeType`s in the `Income`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its better if you can re arrange your classes like this. Then you can write a common method for boath.

```
class Transaction {

 public virtual Type type{get;set;}
}

class Income : Transaction
{

}

class Expense : Transaction
{

}

class ExpenseType : Type
{

}

class IncomeType : Type
{

}
```

Comment: While it did answer my question, how do you eager-load entities in a scenario like I described above?